# sounds play with delay on mouseover mp3, Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, background-music

I am working on wordpress site. In this site i need to play sounds on mouseover, everything is well, but something is wrong, and I dont know why?

There is delay when `mouseover` on the button.

please check the link http://barkingspidertheatre.com.au/new/

here is my code

**JavaScript**

```
function doPlay(what){
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML='<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_mini.swf?autoplay=1" width="200" height="20">'
        +'<param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_mini.swf?autoplay=1" />'
        +'<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />'
        +'<param name="autoplay" value="1" />'
        +'<param name="FlashVars" value="mp3='+what+'" />'
        +'</object>';
    }
    function doStop(){
        document.getElementById('music').innerHTML='';
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo("url");?>/roving-butterflies-penelope-ulysses/?ajax=true&amp;width=108%&amp;height=105%" rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" onMouseMove="javascript:doPlay('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/songs/Harp_gliss_wind_chimes_short_BLASTWAVEFX_15022.mp3')"  onMouseOut="doStop();">


<div class="music_player" id="music"></div>
```

Can any one tell me how can i remove delay on mousover play sound.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with html5 you can access the `audio api` directly, you can do something like below instead of creating object tag for playing the sound:

```
function doPlay(what){
    var snd = new Audio(what); // buffers automatically when created so no delay
    snd.play();
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. but i am not friendly with html5. can you explain me little. how can i use this example.

Comment: updated with your function name. keep your html part as it is and try above javascript function in place of your `doPlay`.

Comment: thanks @Samita. Can i use mp3 files? i use this code but nothing happened. do you know where is problem?

Comment: I use wav files. its working for this. but on mousout how can i use stop function?

Comment: if you keep this sound object global, then I believe you can use snd.pause() for stopping it.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. that was my mistake. just onMouseMove was the big problem.